# Why isn't the asteroid question moved?

Tags: discussion

As far as I percieved it until now every question on Skeptics.SE should question a certain claim or (better and) provide sources for that claim (unless it is a widely know one).

The question about [chances that an asteroid will hit the earth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/458/what-are-the-chances-that-a-deadly-asteroid-will-hit-earth-in-the-next-decade) has neither a claim that this happens or a source for a statement like that. I actually think that this is an interesting topic to discuss, but there were other interesting topics that got closed down very quick (because there were no skeptic claims).

I voted for closing the question, the vote got marked als helpful, yet moderators and high rep members supply answers to the question. I don't think that it would be good to actually close the question any longer, but it should be moved to astronomy.SE.

Answer (score 2):

On review, the question has been moved. Thank you.

Comment: And as to why: because it was an old question, asked before our standards changed and asked before there even *was* an [Astronomy.SE]!

Comment: And now Astronomy is closing.  :(  Although it may go to Physics.